# javascript function NOT returning correct data, using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery - I am trying to make an AJAX call to my server to validate username availability. So inside my form validation I have a call to the function below.

NO MATTER WHAT, it is always returning the "status:0, message:Unknown error validating username", which are my 'catch all' defaults.

However the console logs shows that I am getting what I expect and the 'status' and 'message' ARE being set correctly, however the return value are the defaults...

this is how I'm am calling the function, and the log that shows me the return.

```
var vun = validUsername( form.username.value );
        console.log( vun );



function validUsername( un ) {
    var username = un;
    var status = 0;
    var message = 'Unknown error validating username.';


    // make ajax call to validate username
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/user/',
        data: { validUsername:username },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    })
    .fail( function( jqXHR ) {

        status = 0;
        message = 'Error, validating username. ' + jqXHR.responseText + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText;

    })
    .done( function( data ) {

        console.log( 'return data = ' + data['DATA'] + 'with a length of : ' + data['DATA'].length );

        if ( data['DATA'].length ) {

            status = 0;
            message = 'That Username is already being used. Please Try a different username.';
            console.log( 'I am here - should be invalid UN. status : ' + status + ', message: ' + message );

        } else {

            status = 1;
            message = 'success.';
            console.log( 'I am here - should be valid UN. status : ' + status + ', message: ' + message );

        }


    });

    return { 'status' : status, 'message ' : message };

}
```

Comment: Your `$.ajax()` call *starts* a process, but the process doesn't finish until the remote server has responded. The `$.ajax()` function returns long before that happens.

Comment: how do i make the return 'wait' for the response?
I have tried putting the return INSIDE the 'done' and 'fail' functions, same result

Comment: Read the linked question - basically, you can't do that. You have to structure your code around the reality of the asynchronous system.